# Should React functional component allways display console.log is this meaning it's rerendering?

Tags: reactjs, rendering

```
function App(props) {
   console.log('test rendering?');
   return <div>app content more components inside</div>
}
```

Message from console.log is displayed everytime something is rendered should it be working that way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. React will call the function each time it needs to rerender. Take the following:

```
const Foo = () => {
  const [bar, setBar] = useState(0);
  console.log('Rendering Foo');
  return <div onClick={() => setBar(bar + 1)}>{bar}</div>
}
```

Each time you click the div, the state changes and React calls the function again in order to rerender the view. Obviously it does not reset the state constants for `bar` and `setBar`, as React is smart enough to persist these values.

**Edit:** It's worth noting that React will not call the function if it doesn't need to. For example:

```
const Wrapper = () => {
  const MyFoo = <Foo />;
  const shouldUseFoo = false;

  return <div>{shouldUseFoo && MyFoo}</div>;
};
```

The console log would not trigger here because the component is not required in the end render.

Comment: So this means that I have something wrong in my code becouse my main component shouldn't be rerendering each time. His childrens should but not him

Comment: Possibly - do you want to share more code? If not, this can be marked as answered I guess.